# search bar causing infinite loop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

Here's parent component:

```
const Page = () => {
  const { user } = useAuth();
  const router = useRouter();

  const [allUsers, setAllUsers] = useState([]);
  const [search, useSearch] = useState("");

  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (user !== null && user.isAdmin) {
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
        api
          .get("/users", {
            headers: {
              authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
          })
          .then((data) => {
            setAllUsers(data.data);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            if (error.message === "Request failed with status code 401") {
              const refresh_token = localStorage.getItem("refresh_token");
              const refresh = api
                .post("/auth/refresh", {
                  refresh_token,
                })
                .then((req) => {
                  if (refresh.data.token && refresh.data.refresh_token) {
                    localStorage.setItem("token", refresh.data.token);
                    localStorage.setItem(
                      "refresh_token",
                      refresh.data.refresh_token
                    );

                    api
                      .get("/users", {
                        headers: {
                          authorization: `Bearer ${refresh.data.token}`,
                        },
                      })
                      .then((req) => {
                        setAllUsers(req.data);
                      });
                  }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  if (error.message === "Request failed with status code 400") {
                    if (error.response.data.message
                      === "Refresh Token não encontrado."
                    ) {
                      router.push("/");
                    }
                  }
                });
            }
          });
      } else if (!user) {
        router.push("/404");
      } else {
        router.push("/auth/login");
      }
    },
    [user, router]
  );

  useEffect(
    () => {
      const filterSearch = () => {
        if (search === "") return allUsers;

        return allUsers.filter((user) => user._id.includes(search));
      };
      const filtered = filterSearch(search);
      setAllUsers(filtered);
    },
    [search, allUsers],
    search
  );

  const useConsultasPagination = (data, page, rowsPerPage) => {
    return useMemo(() => {
      return applyPagination(data, page, rowsPerPage);
    }, [data, page, rowsPerPage]);
  };

  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(5);
  const keys = useConsultasPagination(allUsers, page, rowsPerPage);

  const handlePageChange = useCallback((event, value) => {
    setPage(value);
  }, []);

  const handleRowsPerPageChange = useCallback((event) => {
    setRowsPerPage(event.target.value);
  }, []);

  if (user !== null && user.isAdmin) {
    return (
      <>
        <Head>
          <title>Search | API</title>
        </Head>
        <Box
          component="main"
          sx={{
            flexGrow: 1,
            py: 8,
          }}
        >
          <Container maxWidth="xl">
            <Stack spacing={3}>
              <Stack direction="row" justifyContent="space-between" spacing={4}>
                <Stack spacing={1}>
                  <Typography variant="h4">Users</Typography>
                </Stack>
              </Stack>
              <UsersSearch
                setAllUsers={setAllUsers}
                allUsers={allUsers}
                search={search}
                useSearch={useSearch}
              />
              <UsersTable
                count={allUsers.length}
                onPageChange={handlePageChange}
                onRowsPerPageChange={handleRowsPerPageChange}
                page={page}
                rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
                results={keys}
                setKeys={setAllUsers}
                keys={allUsers}
              />
            </Stack>
          </Container>
        </Box>
      </>
    );
  } else {
    router.push("/404");
  }
}
```

And here's search bar's component:

```
export const UsersSearch = (props) => {
  const {
    setAllUsers = () => {},
    allUsers = [],
    search = "",
    useSearch = () => {}
  } = props;

  const { user } = useAuth();
  const router = useRouter();

  const SetSearch = (value) => {
    useSearch(value);
  };

  const HandleInputChange = (event) => {
    console.log('a')
    event.preventDefault();

    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    if (value === "") {
      SetSearch("")
    } else {
      SetSearch(value);
    }
  };

  if (user.isAdmin) {
    return (
      <>
        <Stack sx={{ gap: 2, flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}>
          <TextField
            fullWidth
            size="small"
            id="search"
            placeholder="Pesquisa pelo id do usuário"
            onChange={HandleInputChange}
            sx={{ maxWidth: 500 }}
          />
        </Stack>
      </>
    );
  } else {
    router.push("/404");
  }
};
```

The problem I'm facing is that, everytime a change the text in the search I get an infinite loop, although the search feature works (and when I remove all the text from the bar it doesn't comes back to the initial allUsers value).

Help me please :)

Changed the useEffect from causing another loop

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be the second `useEffect` hook in the `Page` component. You are passing `search` and `allUsers` as dependencies ***and*** unconditionally enqueueing a `allUsers` state update. This triggers the render looping.

```js
useEffect(
  () => {
    const filterSearch = () => {
      if (search === "") return allUsers;

      return allUsers.filter((user) => user._id.includes(search));
    };

    const filtered = filterSearch(search);
    setAllUsers(filtered); // (2) <-- unconditional state update
  },
  [search, allUsers],      // (1) <-- allUsers dependency
  search
);
```

You are also passing a third argument to `useEffect` for some reason, but this is ignored.

You can refactor the `useEffect` hook to eliminate `allUsers` as an external dependency by using a functional state update to access the previous `allUsers` state value.

Example:

```js
useEffect(
  () => {
    setAllUsers(allUsers => {
      if (!search) return allUsers;
      return allUsers.filter((user) => user._id.includes(search));
    });
  },
  [search],
);
```